# C# convert formatted string (31.2k) back to number (31240)

Tags: c#, string, formatting, format, number-formatting

Let's say I have this code:

```
int i = 31240;
string Number = ((double)i / 1000).ToString("0.#k");
```

I get this result as a string for Number: 31,2k

And now, I wanna do the exact opposite, that is to take this string "31,2k" and take it back to 31240 or even to 31200, but I don't know how to do...
Any idea?

---

Someone said that was impossible.
BUT Finally I found the perfect way to achieve my goal. I post the solution for those who could be willing to know.
The use is simple, and it allows to make 2 kind of conversions:

- Thousands, Example: 45831 <=> 45,8k <=> 45831
- Millions, Example: 123852376 <=> 123,5m <=> 123852376

Comment: Have do you suppose to get 31240 from 31,2k? What if the original number had been 31260 how would you know the difference between 31,2k and 31,2k?

Comment: Yeah you are definitely true, I will just to a custom class for this purpose, thanks for your time

Comment: As a generale rule, if you solve it yourself, you post the solution in an answer and then accept it.

Comment: Sorry but you didn't solve the original question ("that is to take this string "31,2k" and take it back to 31240") you solved a different puzzle. How can I pretty print a number and still be able to keep the numeric value

Comment: @xanatos, I couldn't do it because you have to wait for 8 hours to answer your own question, but I will do it, thanks for reminding me that

Comment: @RuneFS actually the word "back" means that it was first converted from a number. In that case, instead of putting this converted number into a string, yo put it into a StringFromInt object. Then when you put that same object into an int, it restores the original number. But if there wasn't the word "back", you would be true, that would simply be impossible to just take a string object like "31.2k" to 31240, because it could also be 31225  as you said

Comment: @RuneFS the solution resides in just using the class, and then replacing "string" in your code by StringFromInt, maybe you should try the example code. Then, your StringFromInt has both information: when used to show the string value, it calls the ToString function. When put back into an int (int NumberBack = MyStringFromIntNumber), it uses the implicit operator and returns the int number stored in the object

Comment: I didn't say your code didn't work I said it does not transform the string 0.#k into whatever was originally formatted. That does mean that the code you now have can't be used to pretty print integers and store the original int value for usage somewhere else

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the solution I went through:

```
public class StringFromInt
{
    public enum FormatStyle
    {
        Kilo = 1000,
        Mega = 1000000
    }
    public int Number;
    public FormatStyle Format
    {
        get
        {
            switch (LimitValueBeforeConversion)
            {
                case 1000: return FormatStyle.Kilo;
                case 1000000: return FormatStyle.Mega;
                default:
                    throw new NotImplementedException("You must implement the code for this kind of value");
            }
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == FormatStyle.Kilo)
            {
                LimitValueBeforeConversion = 1000;
            }
            else if (value == FormatStyle.Mega)
            {
                LimitValueBeforeConversion = 1000000;
            }
        }
    }
    public int LimitValueBeforeConversion
    { get; set; }
    public static implicit operator int(StringFromInt s)
    {
        return s.Number;
    }
    public static implicit operator StringFromInt(int number)
    {
        StringFromInt s = new StringFromInt(number);
        return s;
    }

    #region Constructors
    public StringFromInt(int number, FormatStyle format)
    {
        this.Number = number;
        Format = format;
    }
    public StringFromInt(int number)
        : this(number, FormatStyle.Kilo)
    {
        if (number >= 1000000)
        {
            this.Format = FormatStyle.Mega;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (Number >= LimitValueBeforeConversion)
        {
            string formatString = "0.#k";
            switch (Format)
            {
                case FormatStyle.Kilo:
                    formatString = "0.#k";
                    break;
                case FormatStyle.Mega:
                    formatString = "0.#m";
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new NotImplementedException("You must implement the code for this kind of value");
            }
            return ((double)Number / LimitValueBeforeConversion).ToString(formatString);
        }
        else
        {
            return Number.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

---

And here is a test program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i = 31240;

        string StringRepresentation = ((double)i / 1000).ToString("0.#k");
        int resultBackWithParse = int.Parse(StringRepresentation.Substring(0, StringRepresentation.Length - 1).Replace(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator, string.Empty)) * 100;
        Console.WriteLine("Base number: " + i.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 35));
        Console.WriteLine("String representation: " + StringRepresentation);
        Console.WriteLine("Int representation With Int.Parse: " + resultBackWithParse.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine();
        StringFromInt MySolutionNumber = i;
        int resultBackWithStringFromInt = MySolutionNumber;
        Console.WriteLine("String representation With StringFromInt: " + MySolutionNumber.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Int representation With StringFromInt: " + resultBackWithStringFromInt);

        Console.WriteLine(new string('=', 35) + "\n");
        i = 123456789;
        StringFromInt MyNumber = 123456789;
        int resultBack = MyNumber;
        Console.WriteLine("Base number: " + i.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 35));
        Console.WriteLine("String representation With StringFromInt: " + MyNumber);
        Console.WriteLine("Int representation With StringFromInt: " + resultBack);

        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```

---

As you can notice, there is no need to use the "new" initializer, I mean no need to do:

```
StringFromInt Number = new StringFromInt(YourNumber)
```

Thanks to the implicit operator, you can do:

```
StringFromInt Number = YourNumber
```

I don't know, but I think it's a good beginning, what do you think?

Anyway, I managed to do what I wanted, so for people who thought it couldn't be done, you see, that's possible :-)

Obviously this can be improved: this version works for thousands and millions only.

Greetings

Answer (score 5):

```
int i = (int)(Double.Parse(Number.Substring(0, Number.Length - 1)) * 1000);
```

We remove the `k` with `Number.Substring(0, Number.Length - 1)`, transform it to double with `Double.Parse`, multiply by 1000 and in the end convert to `int`. The order of the things is very important! The first time I was doing `(int)Double.Parse(Number.Substring(0, Number.Length - 1)) * 1000` that was converting to int before multiplying (so I got 31000 instead of 31200)

I'll add that if I had to write that code, I would sleep VERY much better if I used the `Decimal.Parse` instead of the `Double.Parse` (so I would be sure against the vagaries of floating points)

I'll add a better method:

```
int i2 = int.Parse(Number.Substring(0, Number.Length - 1).Replace(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator, string.Empty)) * 100;
```

This is much more interesting. We remove the `k` as in the other method but this time we remove the `,` from the `string` too and we multiply by 100.

The interesting trick is that instead of simply ("bovinamente" in italian slang, as bovines would do) replace the `,` with an empty string, we get the current decimal separator (`CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator`) and we replace THAT with an empty string.

Clearly had we used another culture in composing the original string (for example the always good `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`) we would use that to get the `NumberDecimalSeparator`

Comment: Requires that the tostring and "fromstring" operations are done with same culture. A reasonable assumption I'd say

Comment: Yeah I wrote my question too fast, because I thought about that. Anyway, do you think there is a way to go back to the exact number? The only way I see is to make a class, a kind of class named StringFromNumber that will save the previous value.

Comment: Well I think I'll go on the custom class, that won't take long to be implemented...anyway regarding the way I asked the question, I will validate this answer. Thanks

Comment: @GianT971 This isn't CSI... You can't Zoom, Enhance, taken! You would have to save it somewhere :-)

Comment: @GianT971 And in the end in your question you wrote `or even to 31200`, so even you knew that it wasn't really possible :-)

Comment: What is CSI?
Actually I was wondering whether there was a builtin type for this kind of operation

Comment: You say that is impossible, I don't agree => I did it, look the question, I just edited it

Comment: @GianT971 CSI is a TV movie. They zoom on low res images and recreate details. They create information where there isn't information. In one episode they were able to see a person in the reflection of an eye taken by a video camera. You now aren't destroying information so it's ok. So it was impossible as written, you change the rules => you change the information.

Comment: +1 for the Replace(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Numberformat).  I needed to do something very similar only with the NumberGroupSeparator.